# ebgaramond gives LaTeX3 Error: Command '\swshape' already defined

Tags: luatex, ebgaramond

Consider:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

```
$ lualatex test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 3
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-21>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2019/11/21 v3.7j configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))

! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\swshape' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.140   \newfontfamily
                    \ebgaramondOsF
?
```

What's going on?

Comment: \swshape is now defined by the kernel, the package should no longer define it. Write to the package author.

Comment: This should be fixed by now. The author of `ebgaramond` sent an update to CTAN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be fixed by an update.

Comment: It is fixed by an update

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Which version of ebgaramond fixes this? I downloaded latest version from CTAN, and the error persists.